# Reading all lines in a file and splitting on multiple strings c#

Tags: c#, string

I am attempting to read all files in a directory and write text to an external file depending on a specific string in the files contained in the directory.

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(pendingFile).Where(line => line.Split(';').Last().Contains("Test1")))
                        {
                            File.AppendAllText(path, line + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
```

How do I specify multiple strings here? like so "Test1", "Test2", "Test3"?

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(pendingFile).Where(line => line.Split(';').Last().Contains("Test1", "Test2", "Test3")))
```

Answer (score 2):

You "do it the other way round"; you don't ask "does this last bit of the line contain any of these strings", you ask "are any of these strings contained in the last bit of the line"

```
var interestrings = new []{"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"};

File.ReadAllLines(pendingFile)
    .Where(line => 
        interestrings.Any(interestring => 
            line.Split(';').Last().Contains(interestring)
        )
    )
```

It's probably worth pointing out your code would be a lot more readable if you didn't try and do it all in the `for` header:

```
var interestrings = new []{"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"};
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(pendingFile))
{

    var lastOne = line.Split(';').Last();
    if(!interestrings.Any(interestring => lastOne.Contains(interestring))
        continue;

    File.AppendAllText(path, line + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

It won't perform significantly differently, because LINQ will (behind the scenes) be enumerating all the lines, but skipping those where the condition doesn't match and only giving you those that does - this loop essentially does the same thing without the chained enumeration

You could get some useful performance boost by not using `Split` (use a substring from the last index of `';'`) and also consider collecting your strings into a stringbuilder rather than repeatedly appending them to a file. Also if you use `File.ReadLines` rather than `ReadAllLines`, you'll incrementally read the file rather than buffering it all into memory:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(10000); //

var interestrings = new []{"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"};
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(pendingFile))
{
    var lastOne = line;

    var idx = line.LastIndexOf(';');
    if(idx == -1)
        lastOne = line.Substring(idx);

    if(!interestrings.Any(interestring => lastOne.Contains(interestring))
        continue;

    sb.AppendLine(line);
}

File.AppendAllText(path, sb.ToString());
```

If the file is huge, consider opening a stream and writing it line by line too, rather than buffering much of it into a stringbuilder

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression instead:

```
.Where(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\;Test\d+$"))
```

(haven't tested this exact piece of code, just giving an idea)